# How get image width to be available for transformWrite

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to set up a FS.store with transformWrite, that scales uploaded images. I do have a max width size. But the scaling should be by integer factor only.

For example, if I have a max width of 100px, and an original image width of 40px, the image should be scaled by an integer factor of 2, which results in a target width of 80px (a factor 3x would result in an image too wide).

To calculate the original width and do the math I've set up the function `scaleToMaxByInteger` that should return the optimal width. For some reason it is not working in the gm transformation. Why?

```
var ScaledStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("ScaledPix", {
    path: pathToScaledFolder,

    beforeWrite: function(fileObj, readStream) {
        return {
            extension: 'png',   // sets extension of file
            type: 'image/png'   // sets content of type field in db
        };
    },
    transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        // calculate max possible size if scaled by integer
        // that will fit into maximal width available
        function scaleToMaxByInteger(readStream) {
            gm(readStream)
                .size({bufferStream: true}, FS.Utility.safeCallback(function (err, size) {
                if (err) {
                    // handle the error
                } else {
                    var maxWidth = 100;
                    var originalWidth = size.width;
                    var scaleInt = Math.floor(maxWidth/originalWidth);
                    var scaleSize = scaleInt * originalWidth;

                    console.log('originalWidth: ' + originalWidth);
                    console.log('scaleInt: ' + scaleInt);
                    console.log('scaleSize: ' + scaleSize);

                    return scaleSize;
                }
            }));
        };

        // Resizing image with no antialiasing
        gm(readStream)
        .sample(scaleToMaxByInteger(readStream)) // >>>>>> This is NOT WORKING
        .stream('PNG')
        .pipe(writeStream);
    }
});
```

Comment: Then, shouldn't the scaling be something like `scaleInt = maxWidth % originalWidth`? It seems more logical to me. Also, what is not working exactly?

Comment: @Kyll gm transform at the end is not working with the scaling function. And the operator does return the remainder or am I wrong? I'm not on my machine now.

Comment: Right. Not in my best state it seems, forget about the %.